# CTE Expression not working

Tags: sql-server, cte

I am trying to get the employee hierarchy as output with empLevel indicating the reporting layer. However, my query returns only one row i.e. The CEO of the company while it's supposed to return all employee names with the organization hierarchy.

```
WITH emp_hier AS
  (
    SELECT BOSS.employee_number, BOSS.name, BOSS.manager, 0 as empLevel
    FROM Employees as BOSS
    WHERE BOSS.manager = ''

    UNION ALL

    SELECT emp.employee_number, emp.name, emp.manager, e.empLevel + 1
    FROM Employees as emp
    INNER JOIN emp_hier as e ON emp.manager = e.employee_number

  )
  SELECT * FROM emp_hier
```

Comment: Please add DDL for tables referenced in the query.

Comment: Do you definitiely have a record where `BOSS.manager = ''`? Could it be `NULL` instead?

Comment: If you see only one row (the "BOSS"), then there is no employee that matches the `(emp.manager = boss.employee_number)` condition.

Comment: When I do the select using the employee number of the BOSS it neatly shows up all the reportees of the BOSS.

Comment: @dukes show us the exact query you use that works. And the exact result  you get from this (non-working) query.

Comment: Adding the `CREATE TABLE` script would help, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your manager column is an INT type, it'll probably be NULL or 0 when it has no manager assigned.

```
WITH emp_hier AS
 (
  SELECT BOSS.employee_number, BOSS.name, BOSS.manager, 0 as empLevel
  FROM Employees as BOSS
   WHERE BOSS.manager is null

  UNION ALL

  SELECT emp.employee_number, emp.name, emp.manager, e.empLevel + 1
  FROM Employees as emp
  INNER JOIN emp_hier as e ON emp.manager = e.employee_number

  )
  SELECT * FROM emp_hier
```

Comment: The manager is not INT , it's a nvarchar. It just gives me the output of anchor query. I am really puzzled at this!!

Comment: Is the `employee_number` also an nvarchar?

Comment: Got it solved!! Some data corruption issue at employee number and it was causing all this chaos. Thanks everyone who helped me in this.